# Change my hardcoded left menu and get the list from my API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have created a menu page using ReactJS which can display the data from an API.

My API is as below:

```
[
  {
   "Name": "Chicken pizza",
   "Category": "Pizza",
   "Type": "non-veg",
   "Price": 376,
   "id": "1"
  },
  {
   "Name": "Paneer Cheese Pizza",
   "Category": "Pizza",
   "Type": "veg",
   "Price": 350,
   "id": "2"
  },{
   "Name": "Orange Juice",
   "Category": "Juices",
   "Type": "veg",
   "Price": 45,
   "id": "3"
  },
  {
   "Name": "Badam Fruit Mix",
   "Category": "Juices",
   "Type": "veg",
   "Price": 50,
   "id": "4"
  },
  {
   "Name": "Vanilla Icecream",
   "Category": "Ice Creams",
   "Type": "veg",
   "Price": 50,
   "id": "5"
  }
 ]
```

From the above API I have implemented the code below to display the items:

```
<div className='items'>                                 
 {filteredData.map(item=>
    <div>
      <div className='itemslist' key={item.id}>
         <ul>
           <li className={item.Type === 'veg' ? 'veg' : 'non-veg'}></li>
           <li>{item.Name}</li>
           <li>₹ {item.Price}</li>
           <img src='/images/pizza1.jpg'/>
           <div className='hr'></div>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
   )}
```

And my functions are :

```
const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(1);

    const [mainArray, setMainArray] = useState();

    const toggleTab = (index, name, item) => {
        let array = item ? item : mainArray;
        setToggleState(index);
        const filteredArray = array.filter((item) => item.Category === name)
        setData(filteredArray);
        };

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const [search,setSearch] = useState("");
        
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData(){
          try {
            const response = await fetch('https://63b6952d1907f863aafa9342.mockapi.io/menu/')
            const data = await response.json();
            setData(data);
            setMainArray(data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        }
    
        fetchData();
      }, []);

    const [vegOnly, setVegOnly] = useState(false);

    const handleVegInputChange = (e) => {
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    setVegOnly(isChecked);
    };

    const filteredData =
    vegOnly === false ? data : data.filter((item) => item.Type === "veg");
```

MY hardcoded left menu to toggle data based on categories is :

```
<ul>
   <li className={toggleState === 1 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>{toggleTab(1); setData(mainArray)}}>All</li>
   <li className={toggleState === 2 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(2, "Pizza")}>Pizza</li>
   <li className={toggleState === 3 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(3, "Bread")}>Bread</li>
   <li className={toggleState === 4 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(4, "Shakes")}>Shakes</li>
   <li className={toggleState === 5 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(5, "Ice-Cream")}>Ice Cream</li>
   <li className={toggleState === 6 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(6, "Cakes")}>Cakes</li>
   <li className={toggleState === 7 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(7, "Juices")}>Juices</li>
 </ul>
```

Now my main problem is to change my left menu which is hardcoded to a single line so that the left menu gets the categories list from my API and I should be able to sort the data based on active category as my previous implementation.

I'm unable to write a function to satisfy the needs of my requirement.

Guide me on how I can get the categories list from API instead of hardcoding and keep my toggle functionality on selecting categories.

I'll share my sandbox link for any further information about the code if required.

https://codesandbox.io/s/qr-menu-smvr6h?file=/src/App.js

Look into this and help me out the way for a solution. However small the solution maybe if it might be helpful for me to increase my knowledge do share me your information and solution.

Answer (score 0):

So ideally you should have another API for GET categories list.
Just in case, you still want to extract categories from products list anyway, you should also have category Id since names can be conflicting (in case there are multiple categories of same name created by user, anyways!). You can then create another array of categories (ideally an object with id and its name), and push only those items that are not already present in the array. This way you have a unique set of categories to display.

https://codesandbox.io/s/qr-menu-forked-ibh97l?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=1404&resolutionHeight=946

Comment: how can I sort the data for it by clicking a particular category after displaying the sidemenu?

Comment: So you need to pass that data dynamically. Please have a look at this. I have now modified it acc. to your needs.
https://codesandbox.io/s/qr-menu-forked-ibh97l?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=1400&resolutionHeight=800